# SQL Server: Select top from each repeated row (Not Distinct)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a select that returns some rows. It may return 1 row for an ID, 2 rows for the same ID as maximum, or no result for an ID. See my select below:

```
SELECT    e.ID, a.Type, e.Name, e.Age, e.email
FROM      InfoEmployee e
          INNER JOIN AnotherTable a ON a.ID = e.ID
WHERE     a.Type in (10,15)
ORDER BY  e.ID asc, a.Type desc
```

it returns following result, for example:

```
ID   |   Type  | Name    | Age | email
100      15      John      20    john@mail.com
100      10      John      20    john@mail.com
120      15      Paul      40    paul@mail.com
121      15      Marie     34    marie@mail.com
121      10      Marie     34    marie@mail.com
150      10      Clarie    21    clarie@mail.com
156      15      Mark      28    mark@mail.com
156      10      Mark      28    mark@gmail.com
```

but I would like to obtain:

```
ID   |   Type  | Name    | Age | email
100      15      John      20    john@mail.com
120      15      Paul      40    paul@mail.com
121      15      Marie     34    marie@mail.com
150      10      Clarie    21    clarie@mail.com
156      15      Mark      28    mark@mail.com
```

That is only one row for each ID, the top one.
I am searching for a fast query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is the **WITH TIES** clause.  (No extra field)

```
SELECT    Top 1 with Ties e.ID, a.Type, e.Name, e.Age, e.email
FROM      InfoEmployee e
          INNER JOIN AnotherTable a ON a.ID = e.ID
WHERE     a.Type in (10,15)
Order By  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By e.ID Order by a.Type Desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you only care about `MAX(Type)` so just aggregate:

```
SELECT    e.ID, MAX(a.Type) Type, e.Name, e.Age, e.email
FROM      InfoEmployee e
          INNER JOIN AnotherTable a ON a.ID = e.ID
WHERE     a.Type in (10,15)
GROUP BY e.ID, e.Name, e.Age, e.email
ORDER BY  e.ID asc, a.Type desc
```

Note: It looks like you only get the `MAX(Type)` value whenever there are two or more rows, for example for `Name = 'Mary'` you only want the one with `Type = 15` and same for `Name = 'John'`- is this really what you need?

Comment: It works but the problem here is that you must group all the fields.

Comment: This is not the right answer for you, it happens to work for this case but it has not been very clear to me what you needed. The accepted answer is really the correct one in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```
;With cte(ID,Type,Name,Age,email)
AS
(
SELECT 100,15,'John'   ,  20,   'john@mail.com'   UNION ALL
SELECT 100,10,'John'   ,  20,   'john@mail.com'   UNION ALL
SELECT 120,15,'Paul'   ,  40,   'paul@mail.com'   UNION ALL
SELECT 121,15,'Marie'  ,  34,   'marie@mail.com'  UNION ALL
SELECT 121,10,'Marie'  ,  34,   'marie@mail.com'  UNION ALL
SELECT 150,10,'Clarie' ,  21,   'clarie@mail.com' UNION ALL
SELECT 156,15,'Mark'   ,  28,   'mark@mail.com'   UNION ALL
SELECT 156,10,'Mark'   ,  28,   'mark@gmail.com'
)
SELECT ID,Type,Name,Age,email from
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By ID   Order by [Type] Desc) AS Latest from cte
)Dt
Where Dt.Latest=1
```

OutPut

```
ID   |   Type  | Name    | Age | email
100      15      John      20    john@mail.com
120      15      Paul      40    paul@mail.com
121      15      Marie     34    marie@mail.com
150      10      Clarie    21    clarie@mail.com
156      15      Mark      28    mark@mail.com
```